# How to write health check for graphql apis without http

Tags: django, kubernetes, graphql

I have a K8s cluster in which there is a pod which has Gjango + Graphql apis.

I need to write a health check job which makes sure that my apis are up and running.

I do not want to use http style request to check the health. Rather I would like to use Django.
Please guide me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for so-called "Liveness Probes" in Kubernetes:

- Command
- HTTP

See: [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

Django and GraphQL are HTTP-based and so you probably should consider using an HTTP probe. If there isn't a specific healthcheck endpoint on your service, you could identifier an exemplar (one that should always work) and use that as the healthcheck.

If you want to use something other than HTTP, your only option is to create some command that exits|returns 0 when successful to signal it's healthy and something else (usually 1) when unsuccessful to signal it's unhealthy.

Comment: I don't think I understood this but may be my question is not self explanatory.
So I need to make sure the health of graphql running inside a docker container. I am not sure how can I get it done.

Comment: I understood the question. You have 2 choices for healthchecking with Kubernetes. Either use HTTP or use some (non-HTTP) binary. Since GraphQL usually runs on HTTP, I think you should use HTTP. If you don't want to use HTTP then, the only alternative is to use the command (binary). Your API needs to either having a specific healthcheck endpoint (that you can query to check that its alive) or you must use an existing method on your API and use that as a proxy for health checking. Please see the link I included for a thorough explanation of how to do health (liveness) checking with Kubernetes.